# Why javaw is not found on my java installation on ubuntu?

Tags: java, ubuntu

I tried to start a program using `javaw demo` and I was prompted with an error message saying that command 'javaw' is not found. I checked my bin folder and javaw was not found. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The `javaw` utility is not available or needed on Linux.  Just use `java` instead.

***Explanation:***

- on Windows, the difference between `java` and `javaw` is that `java` launches a new Windows console and `javaw` doesn't.
- on Linux, the `java` command does not launch a new console, and hence there is no need for a `javaw` variant.

Comment: Not only is it not require - it does not even exist on Linux systems.