# How can I run java file with parameters on linux?

Tags: linux, bash, jar

I want to write .sh script on linux.
in .bat file I write this :

```
@echo off
start .\jre7\bin\javaw.exe -jar .\my.jar myfirst_p mysecond_p
exit
```

How can I do that in linux?

Comment: `./path/to/java -jar ./my.jar myfirst_p mysecond_p &`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Unix/Linux you do:

```
/full/path/to/java -jar my.jar myfirst_p mysecond_p &
```

Comment: Perhaps you should add the ampersand to have it running in background (I think that's what `start`is supposed to do).

Comment: in .sh file just I copy it ?

Comment: Yes you can just place this line in a .sh file and run it as `sh ./script.sh`

Answer (score 2):

Check the location of Java with `which java`.
If java is not on PATH than use

```
/full/path/to/java -jar my.jar param1 param2
```

Usually parameters that are used by java programs are with -D perfix

```
/full/path/to/java  -DmyparamWithD=3 -jar my.jar param1 param2
```

Note `javaw` is not used in linux and you can use `java` directly:

[Why javaw is not found on my java installation on ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14331406/why-javaw-is-not-found-on-my-java-installation-on-ubuntu)