# Location of javaw on the Mac

Tags: macos, javaw

I have a shell script on the Mac which looks for `javaw`. i.e.:

```
#!/bin/sh
javaw -version 2> /dev/null
if [ $? == 0 ]; then
  javaw -jar some.jar
else
  echo "Java Runtime not installed or JRE executable not in PATH"
fi
```

but it gives this error when I run it:

```
Java Runtime not installed or JRE executable not in PATH
```

Clearly it can't find `javaw`. So, my question is - where is `javaw` on Mac OS X [Version 10.10.2 (14C109)]?

==== UPDATE

Java is installed. e.g:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Is Java installed? (it won't be "out-of-the-box")

Comment: It seems to be. See the update above.

Comment: This may take a while to run, but should find it `sudo find -x / -name javaw 2> /dev/null`

Comment: Neat, thanks - haven't seen the `-x` flag before. The results - given that I had Java installed I assumed `javaw` would also be installed. Using `find` it turns out it is not.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14331697/942774

Answer (score 2):

mac or linux: `java -jar xxx.jar &`

win: `javaw -jar xxx.jar`